# How can I solve "Error: Failed to query inventory..." (Android, Eclipse, LibGDX)

Tags: android, eclipse, libgdx, inventory

Sometimes (but not always) on resuming the app I get the message:

```
Error: Failed to query inventory:
IabResult: Remote exception while refreshing inventory.
(response: -1001:Remote exception during initialization)
```

Here is my restorePurchases() method. It happens on Resume().

```
@Override
public void restorePurchases() {
    try {
        if (mHelper.isSetupDone() && !mHelper.isAsyncInProgress() && isInternetConnected()) {
            ArrayList<String> additionalSkuList = new ArrayList<String>();
            additionalSkuList.add(productID_hints3);
            additionalSkuList.add(productID_noads);
            additionalSkuList.add(productID_unlockBlockX + "2");
            additionalSkuList.add(productID_unlockBlockX + "3");
            additionalSkuList.add(productID_unlockBlockX + "4");
            additionalSkuList.add(productID_unlockBlockX + "5");
            additionalSkuList.add(productID_unlockBlockX + "6");
            additionalSkuList.add(productID_unlockBlockX + "7");
            additionalSkuList.add(productID_unlockBlockX + "8");
            additionalSkuList.add(productID_unlockManyBlocks);
            mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(true, additionalSkuList, null, mGotInventoryListener);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        complain("Error querying inventory.");
    }
}
```

What should I do to prevent the error? What does it really mean?

[image: Error message]

Comment: Firstly I would log an exception stacktrace as well.
`complain("Error querying inventory.", e);`

Comment: I'm afraid I don't have the stacktrace. Users just get this message and I don't know why and when. I want to find out what "Remote exception during initialization" means.

Comment: Did you get any solution?

Comment: Did you find any solution?